# Firefox table border collapse bleed in

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a table with a thead and a tbody. I add a border-bottom to the thead and a background-color on the td in the tbody there seems to be some bleed in. This only happends in firefox :

Requirements :

- It needs to look exactly the same in chrome firefox
- You can't use empty cells
- border-collapse cannot be changed

```css
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  font-size:20px;
}
thead {
  border-bottom:20px solid green;
}
thead td {
  border-right :2px solid blue;
}
tbody td {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">lorem</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: add some opacity to the green color or make transparent and you will see more strange behavior

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @RMo The question is how to make the result look the same in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: If I you don't want to modify any code the only way to fix the bug on firefox is to make a bugreport to Mozilla so they can adress it on their end. That may take a while tough.

Comment: @RMo already did https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1478433

Answer (score 0):

The bug seems to be related by the fact that the `td`'s in the first `tr` in the `tbody`, don't share the same borders as the `td`'s in the last `tr` in the `thead`. This is happening because of the `colspan="4"`.

A way to circumvent this issue is to put in a `tr` at the top of the `tbody`, that no-one can see ( because it has no height ).

```css
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  font-size:20px;
}
thead {
  border-bottom:20px solid green;
}
thead td {
  border-right :2px solid blue;
}
tbody td {
  background-color:red;
}
tbody>tr:first-child{
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">lorem</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or maybe.. this alternative where I removed the bottom-border, but replaced it by a green row.

```css
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  font-size:20px;
}
thead td {
  border-right :2px solid blue;
}
tbody td {
  background-color:red;
}
th:last-child{
  height: 20px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">lorem</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

PS: You should use `th` instead of `td` in headers

Comment: @Stephen Is having no empty cells a requirement? Then you should add that to the question.

Comment: There are other ways I suppose. One is not using `border-collapse: collapse`. The other is ensuring that the same `th`'s in the last `tr` of the `thead` and the `td`'s in the first `tr` of the `tbody` are having `colspan` in the exact same positions.

Comment: @MrLister I added some requirements